# Why do I get a TypeError when calling max function?

Tags: python

My optimization is meant to print cycling but it prints type error.

Also how can I do very? I want a variable that multiplies things by 3.

```py
good = 100
bad = -100
verybad = 3 * bad

burncalories = good

destroyknees = verybad

# ALSO THIS DOESN'T WORK
# very = 3 * 
# destroyknees = very bad


running = (burncalories * 10, destroyknees)  # score 700

cycling = (burncalories * 8)  # score 800

walking = (burncalories * 2)  # score 200

bestone = max(running, walking, cycling)

print(bestone)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're asking two questions at the same time, it might be a good idea to edit out the question for `very` and make a separate question for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My optimization is meant to print cycling but it prints type error.

There are two errors here:

- you are mixing unrelated types - `cycling` and `walking` are of type `int`, while `running` is a tuple of two elements; maybe you meant to do `running = burncalories * 10 + destroyknees`
- `max` operates on *values*, not variables, so it is going to return the maximum *value*, not the variable name (which has no real consistence once the code is running).

To obtain the result you want you need to put the names inside the values you are max-ing. A simple way may be to have your "activities" consist of a tuple `(value, name)`, e.g. `cycling = (burncalories * 8, "cycling")`. Then, doing `max` on these values is going to return the couple `(value, name)`, of which you can print the second element. To avoid repetition, you can just put them all in a list, like this:

```
activities = [
    (burncalories * 10 + destroyknees, "running"),
    (burncalories * 8, "cycling"),
    (burncalories * 2, "walking")
]

value,activity = max(activities)
print(activity, ":", value)
```

Alternatively, you may use a `dict` to associate the name of the activity to the value, and doing a `max` passing the `key` argument to specify what field to consider.

```
activities = {
    "running": burncalories * 10 + destroyknees,
    "cycling": burncalories * 8,
    "walking": burncalories * 2
}

activity,value = max(activities.items(), key = lambda kv: kv[1])
print(activity, ":", value)
```

(`activities.items()` returns a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs contained in the `activities` dictionary; the `key` argument is a function that is invoked by `max` to ask for each element what value to consider in the `max` operation; `lambda kv: kv[1]` is a lambda function receiving the `(key, value)` tuple and returning just the value part)

For more complex cases a fully-fledged `Activity` class may be preferable.

---

> Also how can I do very? I want a variable that multiplies things by 3.

That's not the way the language works, variables store values, they do not act as macro-like text substitution. The most similar thing you could do in Python would be to make a function

```
def very(value):
    return 3 * value


destroyknees = very(bad)
```

but I don't think it's really an improvement in the code.

Comment: @chwaraeon forgot a `]`, try now.

Comment: The line with the error is value,activity = max(activities)

Comment: Now your first one works perfectly. I haven't tried the second one yet. It looks much more complicated.

Comment: The second one works as well and thank you for all the explanation. Tutto funziona perfettamente, grazie mille.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was not working because you were trying to pass tuples to the `max` function. Moreover, you were trying to get the maximum value, not the string related to this value. I have used a dictionary to make it work:

```
import operator

good = 100
bad = -100
verybad = 3 * bad

burncalories = good

destroyknees = verybad

# ALSO THIS DOESN'T WORK
# very = 3 * 
# destroyknees = very bad


running = burncalories * 10 + destroyknees  # score 700

cycling = burncalories * 8  # score 800

walking = burncalories * 2  # score 200

dict_sport = {"running": running, "cycling": cycling, "walking": walking}
bestone=max(dict_sport.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

print(bestone)
```

Comment: It prints 1000. I want it to print cycling.

Comment: Thank you it works now but it looks very complicated and still you have to type each name twice (once with and once without the quotation marks, like in Jasmijn's answer).

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `TypeError` because `running` is a `tuple` and the other ones are `int`s. From the comments, it looks like you want to add the values.

```
running = burncalories * 10 + destroyknees  # score 700
```

Now, if you want it to print `cycling` instead of `800`, we can use tuples:

```
best_value, best_one = max((running, "running"), (walking, "walking"), (cycling, "cycling"))

print(best_one)
```

This works, because comparing tuples compares them one by one, stopping at the first one that isn't equal: `(1, 'something') < (2, 'something else')`

Comment: Thank you, this is working. But is there a way to write each option once? Or do I have write each one with and without the quotation marks?

Comment: You could use a dictionary for that, but I recommend opening a separate question for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The result printed is a tuple:

```
(1000, -300)
```

This is caused by the variable initialization: `running = (burncalories * 10, destroyknees)` This initializes `running` as such:  `running = (1000, -300)` 
In order to compute the numerical value of running, the initialization should be written with a + operator:

```
running = (burncalories * 10 + destroyknees)
```

Second question:

> Also how can I do very? I want a variable that multiplies things by 3.

You are seeking to operate on a given value. The simplest way of doing this is with a function.

```
def verybadFunc(num):
    return num * 3

print(verybadFunc(bestone))
```